# Filter Pivot Table With Date Filter Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have problem with below code.

```
Worksheets("print").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("day").ClearAllFilters
    Worksheets("print").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("day").CurrentPage = _
        "5/8/2023"
```

I need to change the date 5/8/2023 to be x = today date, or x = range("g2").value

it's not working and keep debug every time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you need, could you show an example of what you need, so I can help you.